# Kommata bei Wortgruppe vor Substantiv?

Tags: punctuation, comma

Ich bin mir aktuell bei einem Beispielsatz sehr unsicher, was die Kommasetzung angeht.

**Möglichkeit a)**

> Es werden verschiedene das Design betreffende Entscheidungen
>   diskutiert.

**Möglichkeit b)**

> Es werden verschiedene, das Design betreffende Entscheidungen
>   diskutiert.

**Möglichkeit c)**

> Es werden verschiedene, das Design betreffende, Entscheidungen
>   diskutiert.

In einer von mir verfassten Arbeit habe ich Möglichkeit b) verwendet. Im Rahmen einer Korrektur hat mir ein Freund gesagt, dass es sich um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz handelt und ich entweder kein Komma oder zwei Kommata setzen soll.

Meinem persönlichen Sprachempfinden nach klingt aber Möglichkeit b) besser. Dabei empfinde ich den Nebensatz - mehr oder weniger - als gleichwertig zu einem Adjektiv an dieser Stelle, wie:

> ... verschiedene, *tolle* Entscheidungen diskutiert

Sind in diesem Fall alle drei Möglichkeiten gültig, oder täuscht mich mein Sprachgefühl und Möglichkeit b) ist kein zulässiger deutscher Satz?

**EDIT:** In den Kommentaren wurde darauf hingewiesen, dass es sich nicht um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz handelt und damit Möglichkeiten a) und b) gültig sind. Dankeschön für die Hilfe!

Comment: Wenn "das Design betreffende" ein eingeschobener Nebensatz wäre, dann müsste man ihn auch durch einschließende Kommas abgrenzen. Es ist aber gar kein eingeschobener Nebensatz (daher ist der Titel falsch). Es ist eine ganz normale Wortgruppe, und die Frage ist, ob "das Design betreffende" und "verschiedene" gleichrangig sind. Dann käme § 71 der amtlichen Rechtschreibung zum Tragen, wonach beide Wortgruppen durch ein Komma voneinander abzugrenzen seien. Das entspräche Möglichkeit b).

Comment: Laß' doch einfach mal das "verschiedene" weg und schau, ob du immer noch Kommata willst - Dann wirst du feststellen, daß "das Design betreffende" eben **kein** Nebensatz ist,.

Comment: Dankeschön für den Tipp! Ich habe gar nicht darüber nachgedacht, ob es es sich vielleicht nicht um einen Nebensatz handeln könnte.
"Gelegentlich kann der Schreibende dadurch, dass er ein Komma setzt oder nicht, deutlich machen, ob er die Adjektive als gleichrangig verstanden wissen will oder nicht." - Wenn ich den Auszug von §71 richtig verstehe, kann ich in diesem Fall bewusst entscheiden, dass ich "verschiedene" und "das Design betreffende" als gleichrangig erachte, oder?

Wäre es dann sinnvoll, wenn ich die Frage zu editiere und den Titel anpasse?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Warum schreibst Du das als Kommentar und nicht als Antwort?

Comment: @Alex: So ist es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es handelt sich hier um eine nachgetragene Partizip- oder Adjektivgruppe. Diese wird im §77(7) der deutschen Rechtschreibregeln behandelt, hierbei geht es um Zusätze und Nachträge (nähere Erläuterungen). Ferner wird dort auf §78(3) verwiesen, der die Kommaabtrennung in solchen Fällen frei stellt. Richtig sind also die Möglichkeiten A) und C).

> Es werden verschiedene das Design betreffende Entscheidungen
>   diskutiert.
>
> Es werden verschiedene, das Design betreffende, Entscheidungen
>   diskutiert.